# QGIS 3.10 how to remove colour from a background layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, symbology, basemap, os-mastermap

I am using QGIS 3.10 and would like to produce a layout map with a white background. I tried the proprieties option by right clicking on the base map layer. In the symbology tab I was able to turn the colour to grey. But I can't find the right option for a white background. Here is an image of what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably changed the default background color. To set it to white, right click on the (empty) background of the print layout an select `Page properties`. Then go to the tab `Item properties` and change the `Background` color by selecting white.

*[If the background color is not white in the QGIS main window as well, then change the Background color in Project Properties in QGIS main window: `Menu Project > Properties > General tab > Background color`.]*

[image]